# It's possible to use google smtp for sending email from my server?

Tags: smtp, spam, gmail

Well, I am becoming crazy to let my email deliver to gmail/hotmail from my new ip.
Last year, i had no problems with my past ip, but now my emails go straight to the spam folder of gmail and hotmail.

I checked with mxtoolbox.com and i am not blacklisted, not an open proxy, rdns is configured the right way, SPF policy is present on the DNS.
My spf is v=spf1 a mx ~all

But, still, I am filtered.

So, I am wondering: since gmail does not accept my emails, it's possible to use gmail smtp server to deliver all mails from my server? AFAIK, it will change all the "from" address, but maybe there is a way to not let it happen?

Comment: Do you have Reverse DNS setup for the outgoing mail server IP. I had an issue with bounce backs sending mail when we didn't have Reverse DNS configured as I believe it is often an indication of spam.

Comment: yes, the rDNS for the outgoing mail server IP it's the same specified in the SMTP helo

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). If nothing comes out (or) you are unable to implement the suggestions, look at a [SMTP Relay Service](http://www.safentrix.com)

Comment: safentrix it's really free for unlimited users?? O_O

Comment: Not for Unlimited users, but for up to 20000 users per domain. See http://www.safentrix.com/faqfeat.html#feat13